# Is there any edit option in sonata_type_model?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a sonata_type_model field which you can see in the screenshot and in the code below. The form allows me to add or remove elements to the multiple model field. Is there any way where I can get a link to edit those models in the dropdown/autocomplete field?

[image: Sonata Model Field Screenshot]

```
->add('items', 'sonata_type_model', ['multiple' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'required' => false])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only the possibility of a sonata, this is impossible. It is necessary to customize the type. But if you a lucky man, try to add 4th argument `->add('items', 'sonata_type_model', ['multiple' => true, 'by_reference' => false, 'required' => false], array('edit' => 'inline'))` This is not work for me, but I don't had any errors. You can try to use sonata_type_model_list if relation is toOne between entities.

Answer (score 0):

To add editing capabilities you should use `sonata_type_collection`.

> The Collection Type is meant to handle creation and editing of model collections. Rows can be added and deleted, and your model abstraction layer may allow you to edit fields inline.

See: [Form Types](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-collection)